# 503 Service Unavailable in Magento 2.1.7 admin

Tags: magento-2.1, error-log

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop and  I have
created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

I need to delete **maintenance.flag** to get rid of the `503 Service Unavailable` error and unlock my **Magento admin** (this problem appears *only* in the admin). The entire error message is:

```
Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
```

There is no .maintenance.flag in the var directory. The `php bin/magento maintenance:status` command returns

```
Status: maintenance mode is not active
List of exempt IP-addresses: none
```

What can be wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not have the necessary write permissions. I solved it this way:

```
cd var/generation
chmod -R 777 Magento
```

Answer (score 3):

try below command to disabled **maintenance** mode:

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable 
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
php bin/magento maintenance:status
```

Please check this link.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-maint.html

Comment: Result of the last command: `Status: maintenance mode is not active` and `List of exempt IP-addresses: none`. What shall I do?

Comment: then please check the Error Logs.. there might be some different error that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

This error refers to the maintainance mode of Magento 2. This mode can be triggered like so (already shown by [@Abhishek Panchal](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/49049/abhishek-panchal)):

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable 
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
php bin/magento maintenance:status
```

These commands are only the PHP wrapper to handle the `.maintenance.flag` file that is located in `var/`.

If you want to be really sure, that the maintenance mode is disabled, remove the `.maintenance.flag`.